# Is there a good way to kill turrets since the update?

Tags: exoplanet-war

Since the update for Exoplanet, turrets have basically made playing the game impossible. It is impossible to rob anyone when they have even 1 turret. How can you kill turrets? You used to be able to just take colony attackers and wreck the turrets, but after the update colony attackers are useless! What is the least expensive way to kill turrets?